# Como tornar uma variável local uma variável de instância para um template ERB com binding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Abaixo exemplifico minha necessidade em um código onde preciso redefinir variáveis como `@dispute = dispute` para que sejam variáveis de instância e o template carregado pelo ERB consiga acessa-las através do `binding`:

```
class Remittance::ExportService
  def initialize(remittance)
    @remittance = remittance
    @template = 'app/views/remittances/letter.text.erb'
  end

  def letters
    tempfile = Tempfile.new(['post', '.txt'])

    @remittance.disputes.each_with_index do |dispute, index|
      @dispute = dispute
      @index = index

      dispute.users.each do |user|
        @user = user

        tempfile.write ERB.new(File.read(@template)).result binding
      end
    end

    tempfile.rewind

    @remittance.post = tempfile
    @remittance.save
  end
end
```

Existe alguma forma de automaticamente tornar as variáveis locais em variáveis de instância utilizando um each ou algum método mágico?

Comment: Este código funciona sem nenhum problema, meu questionamento tem como foco melhorias e a possibilidade de aprendizado. Talvez não exista a possibilidade de fazer o que desejo que é eliminar as 3 declarações a mais que este código tem.

Comment: Estudando sobre Binding me parece que você teria acesso a todas as variáveis locais dentro do seu template, sem precisar criar variáveis de instância. Bastaria acessá-las sem o @ na frente.

Comment: Sim, tenho! Mas utilizo esse mesmo template em outros lugares onde o acesso a variável é por instância. Seria uma resposta valida sua observação tambem. Vou aguardar mais e ver se consigo outra resposta. Se existir essa possibilidade tambem, pelo que estou vendo talvez não exista.